# Why is my module scaling when I parent bones to it?

Tags: bones

I just spent time rigging up this character but as so as I parent the bones the module scales up super big but the bones stay the same size.

I have no idea whats going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you scaled the object and/or the armature in object mode without applying the scale.

Select the object, press <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>, a dropdown menu should appear. Click on "Scale" (should be the 3rd option in the dropdown).

Do the same with the armature.